# How to set path to the public folder correctly when using Next.js static export?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a simple Next.js project which I would like to export using the static export functionality (`next build && next export`).

Initially I had problems with the css and js not loading but I could fix these by setting `assetPrefix: './'` in the next.config file. However the statically exported site still could not reach the static assets in the public folder using relative paths.

For example I have an image there, which I would like to use as a background.

`.classname { background-image: url('/bg.svg')}`

This works in localhost (`next dev`), but not in the static export.

I have set absolute urls instead of relative and that fixed the issue with the background, but I would like to use exported site on any machine without setting the absolute urls every time, plus this did not worked with the local fonts I have in the public folder.

Is there a way to reach the public folder in the static build using relative paths?

Comment: static assets in the /static folder should be accessed like "/static/img/partners". Relative paths are not needed.